# Zoomable layout in android

Tags: android, dictionary, coordinates, zooming

I want to something like to map. I have class, where I'm using ScaleGestureDetector and my bitmap is centered, but after zoom, this bitmap isn't centered. I have coordinates, and I want to implement my vision to android. My object should be centered and I want to be able to zooming and moving screen around this object, this is just all. I have x and y, for example x=14500 and y=50000 and this is always center and I can zoom and slide this "map". I will put another point, objects, but I dream about this code.
Thanks for any help

```
public class GPS extends ActionBarActivity {


Button btnShowLocation;
GPSTracker gps;
TextView textView;



public void clickOnButton(View v) {
    setContentView(new ZoomableView(this));

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

}

public class ZoomableView extends View {
private Drawable image;
private float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
Bitmap bitmap;
private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;
private float mAngle;

public ZoomableView (Context context) {
    super(context);
    image = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    setFocusable(true);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context,
            new ScaleListener());
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}

@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    mWidth = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    mHeight = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // Set the image bounderies
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    image.draw(canvas);
    int cx = (mWidth - bitmap.getWidth()) >> 1;
    int cy = (mHeight - bitmap.getHeight()) >> 1;

    if (mAngle > 0) {
        canvas.rotate(mAngle, mWidth >> 1, mHeight >> 1);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, cx, cy, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 100, 10000, null);
    canvas.restore();
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 5.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: do u want the zoom in & out feature in any ImageView ? like the gallery app ?

Comment: This should work as google maps, there I have map, and I can zoom in and out track. If I have two points, where distance is long I have to zoom out, and when I have two point that are near I can zoom in and have better view.